# How to color a button according to a condition in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm a beginner in python and especially with the Bokeh library. Here's my problem: I would like to create a button that colors itself according to a condition.

This condition would be: if at least one element is equal to the green color code the button is colored green, if at least one element is equal to the orange color code the button is colored orange, if at least one element is equal to the red color code the button is colored red.
Here's what I tried to do:

```
coord_elements1 = [np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"Std_CaO_minmax"],2), 
                   np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"Ind_Si_minmax"],2), 
                   np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"A_F_minmax"],2)]



color1 = coord_elements1.copy()
for k, x in enumerate(color1):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        color1[k] = "#F81515"
    elif abs(x) < 0.35:
        color1[k] = "#088A08"
    else:
        color1[k] = "#FAB20A"

coord_elements2 = [np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"aaa_minmax"],2), 
                   np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"bbb_minmax"],2), 
                   np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"ccc_minmax"],2)]

color2 = coord_elements2.copy()
for k, x in enumerate(color2):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        colo2[k] = "#F81515"
    elif abs(x) < 0.35:
        color2[k] = "#088A08"
    else:
        color2[k] = "#FAB20A"

etc...

if enumerate(color1 or color2 or color3 or color4) == "#088A08":
    button = Button(label="success", button_type="success")
elif enumerate(color1 or color2 or color3 or color4) == "#F81515":
    button = Button(label="danger", button_type="danger")
else:
    button = Button(label="warning", button_type="warning")
```

This is what I get:

[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s2xZ.png)

We can see that in the graph everything is in green but the button is in orange.

Please, can someone help me?

(I'm new to StackOverflow, be indulgent)

This is the visualization with the original code:

[button2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDBkz.png)

I found the answer to my question, here is the whole code :

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import os 
    import numpy as np
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, save
    from bokeh.io import output_notebook
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool,DatetimeTickFormatter,CustomJS
    from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap#,log_cmap
    from bokeh.layouts import row, gridplot, widgetbox 
    from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs,Div,TextInput,AutocompleteInput, Panel, DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, HTMLTemplateFormatter,Button #, RadioButtonGroup, Select, Slider,
    from bokeh.models import Column
    from bokeh.util.browser import view



    ex = np.array([[102.11,2.46,1.45,0.04,-0.03,0.01,0.52,-0.32,0.04],
                   [94.38,2.63,1.48,0.04,0.04,0.03,-0.45,0.45,0.26],
                   [96.68,2.70,1.46,0.01,0.07,0.01,-0.16,0.77,0.11],
                   [95.16,2.46,1.37,0.03,-0.03,-0.05,-0.35,-0.32,-0.56],
                   [95.36,2.56,1.35,0.03,0.01,-0.06,-0.33,0.14,-0.70],
                   [102.11,2.46,1.45,0.04,-0.03,0.01,0.52,-0.32,0.04],
                   [94.38,2.63,1.48,0.04,0.04,0.03,-0.45,0.45,0.26],
                   [96.68,2.70,1.46,0.01,0.07,0.01,-0.16,0.77,0.11],
                   [95.16,2.46,1.37,0.03,-0.03,-0.05,-0.35,-0.32,-0.56],
                   [95.36,2.56,1.35,0.03,0.01,-0.06,-0.33,0.14,-1.4]])
    data_ex = pd.DataFrame(ex,columns =["Std_CaO","Ind_Si","A_F","Std_CaO_ecart","Ind_Si_ecart",
                                        "A_F_ecart","Std_CaO_minmax","Ind_Si_minmax","A_F_minmax"], 
                           index = [1904000058, 1904000101, 1904000102, 1904000093, 1904000092,
                                    1904000078, 1904000121, 1904000122, 1904000193, 1904000192])

    # Last sample number of the default index

    numero = data_ex.index[-1]

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=data_ex)


    ### cement index

    label_elements = list(["Std_CaO","Ind_Si","A_F"])
    coord_elements = [np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"Std_CaO_ecart"],2), np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"Ind_Si_ecart"],2), 
                      np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"A_F_ecart"],2)]



    coord_elements2 = [np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"Std_CaO_minmax"],2), np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"Ind_Si_minmax"],2), 
                      np.round(data_ex.loc[numero,"A_F_minmax"],2)]



    couleur1 = coord_elements2.copy()
    for k, x in enumerate(couleur1):
        if abs(x) >= 1:
            couleur1[k] = "#F81515"
        elif abs(x) < 0.35:
            couleur1[k] = "#088A08"
        else:
            couleur1[k] = "#FAB20A"

    couleur2 = coord_elements2.copy()
    for k, x in enumerate(couleur2):
        if abs(x) >= 1:
            couleur2[k] = "#F81515"
        elif abs(x) < 0.35:
            couleur2[k] = "#088A08"
        else:
            couleur2[k] = "#FAB20A"


    from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter

    Cement_indicators = figure(x_range = (-1, 1.05), y_range = label_elements,title = "cement index",plot_height = 240, plot_width = 650)
    Cement_indicators.xaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0%")


    Cement_indicators.segment(x0 = list(np.tile(0, len(label_elements))), 
                 y0 = list(np.array(range(len(label_elements))) + 0.5), 
                 x1 = coord_elements, 
                 y1 = list(np.array(range(len(label_elements))) + 0.5), 
                 color = list(couleur1), 
                 line_width = 25)

    Cement_indicators.toolbar.logo = None 
    Cement_indicators.toolbar_location = None

    # Last sample number of the default index

    numero = data_ex.index[-1]

    #output_notebook()

    output_file("DEV_EN.html")



    numero = str(numero)

    data_ex = data_ex.to_json()
    #####################################################################################################
    #                                       UNDER DEVELOPMENT                                           #
    #####################################################################################################
    #                                                                                                   #
    # Callback function to change indicators when changing sample numbers (JavaScript required)         #
                                                                                                        #
    callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=data_ex), code="""                                             #
        var data = source.data;                                                                         #
                                                                                                        #
                                                                                                        #
        source.change.emit();                                                                           #
    """)                                                                                                #
                                                                                                        #
    text_input = TextInput(value= numero, title="Sample No.",width=100,height=45,align = "center")      #
    text_input.js_on_change('value', callback)                                                          #
                                                                                                        #
                                                                                                        #
    # def update_numero(attr, old, new):                                                                #
    #     text_input = TextInput(value=numero, title="N° échantillon")                                  #
    #     text_input.on_change(numero, update_numero)                                                   #
    #####################################################################################################

    # The answer to my question :

    couleur = couleur1 + couleur2

    if "#F81515" in couleur: 
        button = Button(label="danger", button_type="danger")
    elif "#FAB20A" in couleur:
        button = Button(label="warning", button_type="warning")
    else:
        button = Button(label="success", button_type="success")




    div = Div(text="""<CENTER><br/>On the x-axis: relative deviation from the factory average on laboratory sample<br/><div style="color:#088A08">Parameter value within the range ± 1 sigma = green </div>
    <div style="color:#FAB20A">Parameter value within the range ± 1 sigma and 3 sigma = orange</div><div style="color:#F81515"> Parameter value deviating by ± 3 sigma = red</div></CENTER>""", width=450, height=100)

    Indicators = Panel(child=gridplot([[text_input,button],[Cement_indicators,widgetbox(div)]],
                                                 toolbar_location = "left"),title="Compliance Indicators")


    template = """
    {% block postamble %}
    <style>

    .bk-root .bk-tabs-header .bk-tab.bk-active{
    background-color: #1fb0e0;
    color: white;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    }


    </style>
    {% endblock %}
    """

    tabs = Tabs(tabs=[Indicators]) 

    save(Column(tabs), template = template)
    view("DEV_EN.html")
```

Comment: what is color1, color2.. etc? And why are you using `enumerate` in this case? Shouldnt it be just basically `color1 == "#088A08" or color2 == "#088A08".. etc` assuming color1 takes in the hex colour string

Comment: @Axois In my original code, I have 4 graphics, color1 corresponds to the colors of the different bars of graph 1, color2 for graph 2 etc....  I will add an image of the graph obtained with the original code.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. I put the whole code if it can be used by anyone.